# Why is a function not executing when accessed from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, import, output

I am trying to make a python program which executes a game which is selected by a user from a bunch of options. For this I created a dictionary which stores the name of the game and its respective function like this:

```
def Game():
    def hangman():
        import Hangman
    games={"a":{"Hangman":hangman()},"b":{"Tic Tac Toe(2 Players)":"TTT"},"c":{"Stone Paper Scissors":"SPS"},"d":{"Guess The Number":"GTN"}}
    print("Which Game would you like to play?(a,b,c,d,e):")
    for choice in games:
        for Game_Name in games[choice]:
            print(choice+":"+Game_Name)
    answer=input()
    if answer.lower() in games:
        for Game_Name in games[answer.lower()]:
            print("You chose "+Game_Name)
            __name__="__main__"
            return games[answer.lower()][Game_Name]
```

If given output **"a"**, it should return the function hangman but when I run the program, I enter the output "a" but then the  function is not executed.
The output is:

```
 NOT
Which Game would you like to play?(a,b,c,d,e):
a:Hangman
b:Tic Tac Toe(2 Players)
c:Stone Paper Scissors
d:Guess The Number
a
You chose Hangman
```

The Hangman file code is as follows:

```
import random
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Fruits =["apple","banana","mango","strawberry","orange","grape","pineapple","apricot","lemon","coconut","watermelon","cherry","papaya","berry","peach","lychee","muskmelon"]
    Applauds=["Good Job!","Correct!","Keep Going"]
    Try=["Try Again","Wrong Answer","You Bad"]
    Wins=0
    Scores=[]
    def Word(Guess,Enter=False):
        global word_guess
        global wrong
        global word
        global word_length
        if Enter:
            if Guess in word:
                new=""
                print(random.choice(Applauds))
                for i in range(word_length):
                    if Guess==word[i]:
                        new+=word[i]
                    else:
                        new+=word_guess[i]
                print(new)
                word_guess=new
            else:
                print(random.choice(Try))
                print(word_guess)
                wrong+=1
        else:
            print(word_guess)
    def Main():
        global word_guess
        global word
        global word_length
        global Wins
        global wrong
        global Scores
        word=random.choice(Fruits)
        picked=[]
        picked.append(Fruits.pop(Fruits.index(word)))
        word_length=len(word)
        word_guess="-"*word_length
        max_wrong=word_length+2
        Word("Nothing")
        print("\nGuess the word!HINT:Fruit")
        Chance=1
        wrong=0
        used=[]
        while wrong<=max_wrong and word_guess!=word:
            print("The word has",word_length,"Letters")
            print("You have",str(max_wrong-wrong),"chances")
            a=input("Guess No."+str(Chance)+":")
            if a in used:
                print(a,"has already been picked!Guess again")
            else:
                used.append(a)
                Word(a,Enter=True)
            Chance+=1
        else:
            if word_guess==word:
                print("You have successfully guessed the word",word,"with",wrong,"wrong answers!")
                Scores.append(wrong)
                Wins+=1
            else:
                print("You lost!The word was",word)
            Y_or_N=input("Do you wish to continue to the next word?:")
            if Y_or_N in ["Yes","yes","Y"]:
                Main()
            else:
                print("You won",Wins,"Game!")
                print("Thanks for Playing")
    Main()
else:
    print("NOT")
```

I am using the "if **name**="**main**" phrase in for it to not directly execute after the function is defined.
Please Help!

Comment: Just one or two uses of `global` should start raising alarm bells that the approach is flawed. Your code is littered with them; it's enough to stop me trying to review this code and I suspect that any fix to your current issues will break down the road

Comment: You didn't store a function in the `dict`; you called the function, and stored the return value `None`.

Comment: to keep function in dictionary you have to use function's name without `()` and arguments - and later you use `()` to execute it. - `d = {"a": hangman}` and `d["a"]()`. BTW: The same is when you want use function as argument in other function - ie. `max(..., key=len)` - it uses `len`, not `len()`, or when in GUI you want to assign function to `Button`.  Often is use name `callback` to describe that you need function's name without `()`